# Getting Error In DateTimeFormatter

Tags: android

I added this jar file joda-time-2.0.jar in my android project . After adding this jar file it cannot taken the .ofpattern() , please solve this one. thank you.

```
    DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
```

Comment: Try forPattern: org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormatter formatter = 
                              DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");

Answer (score 0):

Using Joda time you would do it like this:

```
String dateTime = "11/15/2013 08:00:00";
// Format for input
DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
// Parsing the date
DateTime jodatime = dtf.parseDateTime(dateTime);
// Format for output
DateTimeFormatter dtfOut = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("MM/dd/yyyy");
// Printing the date
System.out.println(dtfOut.print(jodatime));
```